# my android emulator shows inverted android screen ? any solutions for

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using emulator screen android target 2.2  system image arm for nexus one.

I'm using eclipse ide for android while running my emulator screen shows inverted screen any solutions to make it correct

[image]

Comment: Click that tilt icon at the right.

Comment: so thats only the solutions so i have to tilt the icon every time i run my emulator ?

Comment: the emulator shouldn't be initializing that way up. Check through the settings (... icon) to see if there is anything in there to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. You can rotate the screen using the following keys.

For Windows: left Ctrl + F12.

For Mac: Fn + Ctrl + F12

See  [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#KeyMapping) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

On that bar to the right with the power button, volume buttons, etc., the two buttons above the one that looks like a camera will rotate the emulator 90 degrees clockwise or counter clockwise.

Comment: it fixes the screen for that instance but i wanna make it default all time ? any solutions

Comment: See Guney's answer for setting it default.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default rotate (portrait). Add to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity>
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
</activity>
```

Your app are going to run only portrait screen.

Comment: I don't still get it do i need to provide orientation for every activity i created in manifest file ? does providing the orientation for activity makes the android home screen orientaion portrait help me out ?  @Guney sir

Comment: @crazyArtist This is not likely to be what you want. This locks your app/activity to run only in portrait mode. The issue is that the emulator is not recognizing orientation. This does not solve that issue.

Comment: @Doomsknight so making this orientation may not let me provide sensors for my app while testing in device  since my app/actiivty   will always be in portrait mode is that u wanna say ?

Answer (score 0):

> This code may help you,add this Manifest file.

```
<activity>
 android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
</activity>
```